# how can i display average of time spent (in_time and out_time) in django? do i use aggregation?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am new to django and i am facing a problem in displaying the average of time 
My database model is

```
from django.db import models


class Employee(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Employee'

    emp_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    department_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class AttendanceRecord(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'AttendanceRecord'

    emp_id = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   # emp_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    miti = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    day = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    in_time = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    out_time = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    punch_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    time_spent = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    difference_time = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.emp_id.name

class Department:
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Department'

    department_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    staff_count= models.IntegerField()
```

My Report view is:
I want to average the in_time so that i can average it and display in the report template. i cant figure out how.

```
from attendance.models import AttendanceRecord



class Report:

    def get_all_employee_data(from_date, to_date):
        all_employee_list = AttendanceRecord.objects.filter(miti__gt=from_date, miti__lt=to_date).order_by(
            '-miti')

        return all_employee_list

    def get_specific_emp_data(from_date, to_date, e_id):
        specific_employee_list = AttendanceRecord.objects.filter(miti__gt=from_date, miti__lt=to_date,
                                                                 emp_id=e_id).order_by('-miti')

        return specific_employee_list
```

My test data looks like this
[TEST DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcwDa.png)

Comment: In your Report Class, you are comparing *miti* with from_date and to_date, however in your model class, you have declared it as as CharField??  Also you have declared a date field in your AttendanceRecord class which can be confused with pythons datetime.date. Also what do the fields *miti* and *date* in your model mean?

Comment: @Angela miti is the nepali date while date in the model is used for english date